# Call to undefined method App\Models\StudentYearSection::setContainer() Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

This is the whole code when i run php artisan db:seed, and I don't expect to have `setContainer()` because i didn't write it.

```bash
  INFO  Seeding database.

  Database\Seeders\AdminSeeder ..................................................................................................... RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\AdminSeeder .............................................................................................. 117.29 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\CurriculumSeeder ................................................................................................ RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\CurriculumSeeder .......................................................................................... 86.05 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\CurriculumCourseSeeder .......................................................................................... RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\CurriculumCourseSeeder ................................................................................... 207.90 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\InstructorSeeder ................................................................................................ RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\InstructorSeeder .......................................................................................... 81.73 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\InstructorCourseSeeder .......................................................................................... RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\InstructorCourseSeeder ................................................................................... 193.32 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\ModeOfLearningSeeder ............................................................................................ RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\ModeOfLearningSeeder ...................................................................................... 34.71 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\ProgramSeeder ................................................................................................... RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\ProgramSeeder ............................................................................................. 29.87 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\RoomSeeder ...................................................................................................... RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\RoomSeeder ................................................................................................ 68.96 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\RoomCourseSeeder ................................................................................................ RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\RoomCourseSeeder ......................................................................................... 203.96 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\ScheduleSeeder .................................................................................................. RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\ScheduleSeeder ........................................................................................... 375.98 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\SchoolYearSemesterSeeder ........................................................................................ RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\SchoolYearSemesterSeeder .................................................................................. 55.88 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\StudentSeeder ................................................................................................... RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\StudentSeeder ............................................................................................ 251.40 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\CourseSeeder .................................................................................................... RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\CourseSeeder .............................................................................................. 65.55 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\StudentCourseSeeder ............................................................................................. RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\StudentCourseSeeder ...................................................................................... 356.62 ms DONE

  Database\Seeders\YearSectionSeeder ............................................................................................... RUNNING
  Database\Seeders\YearSectionSeeder ........................................................................................ 100.53 ms DONE


   BadMethodCallException

  Call to undefined method App\Models\StudentYearSection::setContainer()

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:67
     63▕      * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     64▕      */
     65▕     protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
     66▕     {
  ➜  67▕         throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
     68▕             'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
     69▕         ));
     70▕     }
     71▕ }

  i   Bad Method Call: Did you mean App\Models\StudentYearSection::setConnection() ?

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php:36
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::throwBadMethodCallException("setContainer")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:2333
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), "setContainer")
```

I tried to make changes to my StudentYearSection model but nothing works.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class StudentYearSection extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['student_id', 'year_section_id'];

    public function yearSection(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(YearSection::class);
    }

    public function student(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'student_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a typographical error in my DatabaseSeeder, I used a model inside it